# Find where relation not null [Mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have function like this

```
recommendModel.find({
        userId: userId
    })
            .populate('recommendedBy',null,{role: '4edd40c86762e0fb12000002'})
            .exec(function....);
```

This part `role: '4edd40c86762e0fb12000002'}` if inside `recommendedBy` no role like this `4edd40c86762e0fb12000002` it will return null like this:

```
  {
      "_id": "579a1600ce5b012224ba0d36",
      "recommendedBy": null,
      "userId": "5798a398e7dc3b242e1f38a5",
      "__v": 0
    }
```

I need if `recommendedBy` is null to not show record, is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On your query add the `.where('recommendedBy').ne(null)`. This will tell the query to (in your case find()) `find()` all matching documents  "where" `recommendedBy` "is-not-equal-to" `null`.

BTW `.ne()` means not equal.

So in your case :

```
recommendModel.find({userId: userId})
    .where('recommendedBy').ne(null)
    .populate(...) // do your population
    .exec(...); // exec
```